# Simple C code works fine on HPUX but segfaults on Linux. Why?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, portability, hp-ux

I have not done any serious C in a long, long time and would appreciate a quick explanation.  The following code compiles and runs fine on HP/UX.  It compiles without any warning on GCC 4.3.2 in Ubuntu (even with gcc -Wall), but segfaults when run on Linux.

Can anyone explain why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *people[] = { "Abigail", "Bob" };

   printf("First:  '%s'\n", people[0]);
   printf("Second: '%s'\n", people[1]);

   /* this segfaults on Linux but works OK on HP/UX */
   people[1][0] = 'R';

   printf("First:  '%s'\n",people[0]);

   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your people array is in fact a `char const *people[]`. Literal strings are typically in read-only memory on many systems. You can't write to them. Apparently, this is not the case on HP/UX.

Comment: D'oh.  I will curl up with my K&R book tonight!

Comment: @Rudy: technically, string literals are only `char *`, and not `const`.  Most compilers place them in a read-only segment though, so attempts to write to them will cause a seg fault.  There are compilers that allow this bad behavior, and it can create huge problems with shared string literals.  In this case, it would be a good idea to define `people` as `char const *` which would generate compile-time warnings/errors when trying to write to `people[1][0]`.

Comment: @Tom I think the constness of string literals is an implementation detail. K&R is unlikely to shed any light on the topic. You might find some information in the gcc manual. I believe older versions of gcc even let you pick the behavior that you want using a compile-time option (-fwritable-strings).

Answer (score 2):

The string literals are in a read-only data segment. Attempting to write to them is a segmentation violation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify string literals.

Comment: You can do anything you like if the memory segmentation allows you to.